# Parsing for errors from Salesforce Connector in Mule ESB

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I'm using Mule ESB 3.4 CE. I have this flow which uses Salesforce connector to create contacts. I want to parse the errors and do some action.

```
....
<sfdc:create config-ref="Salesforce" type="Contact" doc:name="Create Contacts">
     <sfdc:objects ref="#[payload]"/>
</sfdc:create>
<expression-component doc:name="Get Successful List">flowVars.listSuccess = ($ in payload if $.success=='true')</expression-component>
<expression-component doc:name="Get Failed List">flowVars.listErrors = ($.errors in payload if $.success=='false')</expression-component>
```

The result of the  is as follows:

```
[[SaveResult  errors='{[1][Error  fields='{[1]Email,}'
  message='A contact with this email address already exists.'
  statusCode='FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION'
 ]
 ,}'
 id='null'
 success='false'
]
, [SaveResult  errors='{[1][Error  fields='{[1]Email,}'
   message='A contact with this email address already exists.'
   statusCode='FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION'
  ]
,}'
id='null'
success='false'
]
]
```

I was able to get the ids by the following expression component:

```
<expression-component doc:name="Get Failed List">flowVars.listIds = (Id in payload)</expression-component>
```

However, I was not able to the statusCode and message in case of errors. I tried various combinations, but I was not able to get it. For e.g. #[(message in (errors in flowVars.listErrors)]. How do I get the StatusCode and the message when Salesforce returns errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flowVars.listErrors will contain a list of Error arrays. Look at the following components for inspiration:

```
<logger message="#[flowVars.listErrors[0][0].message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

<scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
   <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
      flowVars.listErrors.each{it->it.each{it2->println('message:'+it2.message)}}
   ]]></scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```

Comment: I was able to see the output in the console, but how can you extract the message and status code into a variable, so I can log into the database?

Comment: I don't know if you can flatten such nested lists in MEL or if that is the best way to log your errors, but you can always follow my example in Groovy and use that approach to extract the message/status code and assign them to a variable.